# Launching Main Activity from app minimized state

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest, android-launcher

I have an application where it has a Login Screen as the Main Activity. Now I want the app to be launched from this screen on each time the app is run. But when I run the app from minimized state, it launches the app from the last activity. I know this is the default behavior.

But, how to over come this, so that the app gets launched from the Home activity only each time.

I tried setting **noHistory** for activity in manifest. But in this case, I will have to override onBackPressed in each activity and start the activity multiple times.

Can any one suggest me other methods to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement this 2 methods in your all your required activity.

```
boolean flag = true;
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart();
    if(flag)
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "start", 1).show();
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Restart 2", 1).show();
        Intent i = new Intent(SecondActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
        finish();
        startActivity(i);

    }
}

@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onRestart();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Restart", 1).show();
    flag = false;
}
```

so when you re open app from background than it will redirect to your LoginActivity.

Comment: in case `MainActivity` is the entry point to the app, it must have been already started, so no need to start it again, `finish()` would be enough.

Comment: @Sanket Kachhela, I ment that you don't need code which starts `MainActivity` from other activities - since `MainActivity` is the entry point, it is already in the backstack, so finishing current activity would be enough to make `MainActivity` visible.

Comment: @a.ch., will that cause anything for backPressed?

Comment: No, no need to override it. You see, suggested solution doesn't solve following case. Let's say we have these activities started: `MainActivity`, `FirstActivity` and `SecondActivity`. If we now in the background and then launched the from Home screen, `SecondActivity` will be finished and new `MainActivity` will be started, resulting in this backstack: `MainActivity`, `FirstActivity` and `MainActivity`. What I'm trying to say is not to call `startActivity(i);` letting all activities except main to finish themseles

Comment: so you mean that we should have to finish all activity in onBackPressed() of all activityes?

Comment: Hey this is causing me an issue. Launching activity is fine here. But think I have launched MainActivity, then go to FirstActivity and to SecondActivity. In Second, I quit the app by pressing home button. Then again launch the app and go to SecondActivity in the sequence. Now if I press back button, it goes to MainActivity rather than going to FirstActivity. Any suggestions?

Comment: have you finish firstactivity while calling startActivity for secondActivity?

Comment: Yes, I do. I think I should not finish that. Problem is when run from background, the flag is set as false. So, the else is executed and the first activity flag is also set as false. So it never comes to if for backpressed